# MongoDB: Order by computed property

Tags: mongodb

in my db I have a collection where documents have a field `score` which is a float (`-1..1`). I can query the db to return the first 20 results ordered by score.

My problem is, that I want to modify the score of a doc with a time penality, based on the field `time_updated`: The older the doc is, the lower the score should be. And the big problem is, that I have to do this on runtime. I could iterate over all documents, update the score and then order by score. But this would cost too much time, since there is a huge amount of documents in the collection.

So my question is: With MongoDB, can I order by a computed property? Is there any way to do that? Or is there a feature in planning for next versions of MongoDB?

Comment: In the aggregation framework it can, as to whether this will work in a performant enough manner to be used in your scenario (I assume adhoc query on a page), depends on how many rows you are computing for, a computed field, like in SQL has to be sorted in memory.

Comment: What do you mean with aggregation framework? Rails or sth like this? There can be about 10.000 rows per user, and I only want to retrieve the top 20. So for now, I have to fetch that 10.000 rows, compute the new time-based score, sort by score and return only 20 rows. I think thats a little bit of overhead. I'm doing that stuff in Rails 3, and I think that's not the fastest method to do it.

Comment: This is the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ it was introduced in 2.1 and it is much like SQLs own with a lot of the features you find in a standard SQL aggregation framework.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly how is the score updated?

If it's simple and can be put in [$add, $multiply, etc., terms](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) then the aggregation pipeline will work well.  Otherwise you'll need to use a simple [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) a for doing the the score updating.

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    emit(this._id, <compute score here from this.score and this.time_updated>);
};

var reduceFunction = function (values) {
    return values[0]; // trivial reduce function since incoming id's are unique.
};
```

For 10000 rows either the aggregation pipeline or a simple MapReduce will probably be sufficiently performant.

For much bigger datasets you may need to use a more complex MapReduce (that actually does a reduce) to be memory efficient.  You might also want to take advantage of [Incremental MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/#incremental-map-reduce).